# How to split an example into two parts?

Tags: environments, theorems, counters

I am trying to have an example (using the theorem environent in amsmath) split in two parts:

Example 1 ...

Some more discussion

Example 1 (continued) ...

What is the best way to do this ?

The code I have so far is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

Consider the following example:

\begin{example}
  $a = b + c$
\end{example}

Now, consider what happens if we add $d$ to $a$:

\begin{example}[continued] % I'd like to have this to output Example 1 (continued)
  $a + d$
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and we can help. This should include `\documentclass` and the packages that you are using. Otherwise it is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot that examples, theorems, etc are not built in.

Comment: Anton: I've added a second MWE, in response to a suggestion by cmhughes, to show how one could automate the insertion of the command `\addtocounter{example}{-1}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can keep most of your previous code. All you need to do is add a few instructions in the preamble -- specifically, load the `ntheorem` package and modify the default definition of `theoremstyle` (the latter is needed only if you want to see `, continued` rather than `(continued)`) -- and remember to issue the command `\addtocounter{example}{-1}` before typing `\begin{example}[continued]`.

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2, ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\section{Some thoughts}
Consider the following example:
\begin{example}
$a = b + c$
\end{example}
Now consider what happens if we add $d$ to $a$:
\addtocounter{example}{-1}
\begin{example}[continued]
$a + d$
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Following up on the suggestion of cmhughes, here's a version of the preceding MWE that's very similar but relieves the author of having to remember to type `\addtocounter{example}{-1}` before starting the example. This is achieved by creating a new environment I've named `contexample`; its style is identical to that of the `example` environment except that it appends `", continued"` to the environment's header. Note that with this device, any example can be "continued" as often as one wishes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2, ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newenvironment{contexample}{
   \addtocounter{example}{-1} \begin{example}[continued]}{
   \end{example}}

\begin{document} 
\section{Some thoughts}
Consider the following example:
\begin{example}
$a = b + c$.
\end{example}
Now consider what happens if we add $d$ to $a$:
\begin{contexample}
$a + d$.
\end{contexample}
And if we wish to continue along these lines, we also find
\begin{contexample}
$x = y$.
\end{contexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the *simplest* way to do what I needed.

Comment: You could put the `\addtocounter{example}{-1}` in the definition- it could go before the `\hskip` in the second `\item`; then you wouldn't have to change the counter manually every time.

Comment: @cmhughes: Great suggestion! I've added a second MWE to illustrate how this would work.

Comment: @Mico. It's not quite what I intended; I was thinking of

`{\item[\addtocounter{example}{-1}\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2, ##3\theorem@separator]}`

which then allows the use `\begin{example}` or `\begin{example}[continued]`

Comment: Thanks, really nifty idea. I guess I wasn't going to go as far as assume that whenever the example environment starts with *any* option given in square brackets, doing so would imply that it's a continuation of the preceding example. Such a working assumption, I'm afraid, will create havoc whenever the *body of the example* happens to start off with a left square bracket, won't it though?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I agree. One could always put a conditional statement in there. Nice solution!

Answer (score 18):

Using the [thmtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package as a front-end for `amsmath` (or `ntheorem`) you can easily achive what you need using the `label=<key>` and `continues=<key>` keys. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[style=definition]{example}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thmcontinues[1]{Continued}

\begin{example}[label=exa:cont]
This is an example.
\end{example}
\begin{example}[continues=exa:cont]
And here's the continuation of the example.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The text displayed is controlled by the `\thmcontinues` command which you can redefine according to your needs, as I did in my example code; by default it will display something like `(continuing from p. <the_page>)`, where `<the_page>` is the page number of the first occurrence of the example.

Answer (score 7):

Adapting cmhughes idea, but keeping the use of the `\newtheorem` command, you can simply make a new theorem type for continuations, and set the counter for that theorem to match the main example counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{excont}{Example}
\renewcommand{\theexcont}{\theexample}

\begin{document}

Consider the following example:

\begin{example}
  $a = b + c$
\end{example}

Now, consider what happens if we add $d$ to $a$:

\begin{excont}[Continued]% I'd like to have this to output Example 1 (continued)
  $a + d$
\end{excont}

\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect solution for my problem

Answer (score 5):

If the continuation always follows the main environment, this works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{exampleinn}{Example}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example \DO}

\newenvironment{example}
  {\exampleinn}
  {%
   \endexampleinn
   \xdef\DO{\theexampleinn\ (continued)}%
  }

\begin{document}

Consider the following example:

\begin{example}
  $a = b + c$
\end{example}

Now, consider what happens if we add $d$ to $a$:

\begin{example*} % I'd like to have this to output Example 1 (continued)
  $a + d$
\end{example*}

\end{document}
```

The `example*` environment can be used any number of times and it will always refer to the main example (but you can't have nesting).

**Acknowledgment.** Thanks to [steffen-sk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/283727/steffen-sk) for suggesting an [improvement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28477/how-to-split-an-example-into-two-parts/28482?noredirect=1#comment1774728_28482).

Comment: You can use this with numberings like `section.number` by moving the `\xdef` part after `\endexampleinn`, so that you don't need to raise the counter manually by one and also replace the `\number\numexpr\value{exampleinn}` part with `\theexampleinn`.
The definition of example environment could then look something like this:
`\newenvironment{example}{\exampleinn}{\endexampleinn\xdef\DO{\theexampleinn\relax\ (continued)}}`

Comment: @steffen-sk It's a really good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The following code defines two environments: `example` and `examplecont`. Note that only the `example` environment increments the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only needed for sample text

\newcounter{example}
\newenvironment{example}{%
\refstepcounter{example}%
{\bfseries Example \theexample}}{}

\newenvironment{examplecont}{%
{\bfseries Example \theexample} (cont\ldots)}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{examplecont}
\lipsum[3]
\end{examplecont}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
If you want a solution that uses an optional argument, here's one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only needed for sample text
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{example}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{continued}}%
{%
{\bfseries Example \theexample (continued\ldots)\quad}%
}%
{%
\refstepcounter{example}%
{\bfseries Example \theexample \quad}%
}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{example}[continued]
\lipsum[3]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I posted this before your edit about using a `theorem` environment

Answer (score 3):

Starting from [here](http://biggamac.blogspot.com/2009/03/continuing-example-in-latex.html), with just a few visual modifications:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\section{Original}

\newtheorem{exampleorig}{Example}

Consider the following example:

\begin{exampleorig}
  $a = b + c$
\end{exampleorig}

Now, consider what happens if we add $d$ to $a$:

\begin{exampleorig}[continued] % I'd like to have this to output Example 1 (continued)
  $a + d$
\end{exampleorig}

\section{Modified}

\newcounter{definition}
\newtheoremstyle{example}
{\topsep} {\topsep}%
{\upshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
{\bfseries\scshape}% Thm head font
{.}% Punctuation after thm head
{1em}% Space after thm head (\newline = linebreak)
{}% Thm head spec

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}

\newtheoremstyle{example_contd}
{\topsep} {\topsep}%
{\upshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
{\bfseries\scshape}% Thm head font
{.}% Punctuation after thm head
{1em}% Space after thm head (\newline = linebreak)
{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{#3} (continued)}% Thm head spec

\theoremstyle{example_contd}
\newtheorem*{example_contd}{Example}

Consider the following example:

\begin{example} \label{ex:example1}
  $a = b + c$
\end{example}

Now, consider what happens if we add $d$ to $a$:

\begin{example_contd}[\ref{ex:example1}] % I'd like to have this to output Example 1 (continued)
  $a + d$
\end{example_contd}

\end{document}
```